# Wold press migration to new server generate lots of errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

today i have migrated my new wp site from dev server to production one.
But now i recive a lot of errors and some plugins doesn't load, why this errors?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

VM571:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'
    at layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js?ver=6.9.2:13

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

(index):774 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at (index):774

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

frontend.min.js?ver=2.7.4:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: elementorModules is not defined
```

I have already tryed to reinstall wordpress and disable all plugins...

Comment: check the loading order of the scripts. might be there some problems with escaping ' "

Comment: seams to be all right... :(

Comment: nobody has any suggestions?

Comment: "seams to be all right..." - I strongly suspect this isn't true. Did you actually compare the network log from your dev site against the network log of your prod site - I think something will be different - maybe a JavaScript file that is missing.